# Refactoring: Round-robin retrieve elements from nested arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, performance, refactoring

I need to go over an array of hashes, with each hash containing a label and an array of data. The end result will be a concatenated string, label first, followed by the data that corresponds to that label.

The input array of hashes looks like:
`[{label: "first", data: [1, 2]}, {label: "second", data: [3, 4, 5]}, {label: "third", data: []}, {label: "fourth", data: [6]}]`
In this example,`max_returns` would be something high like: `10`

```
def round_robin(arr, max_returns)
  result = ''
  i = 0 # number of grabbed elements
  j = 0 # inner array position
  k = 0 # outer array position
  l = 0 # number of times inner array length has been exceeded
  while i < max_returns do
    if k >= arr.length
      j += 1
      k = 0
    end
    element = arr[k]
    if element[:data].empty?
      k += 1
      next
    end

    if j >= element[:data].length
      l += 1
      k += 1

      if l > arr.length && i < max_returns
        break
      end
      next
    end
    result += element[:label] + ': ' + element[:data][j].to_s + ', '
    i += 1
    k += 1
  end
  result
end
```

Based on the input given above, output should be:
`"first: 1, second: 3, fourth: 6, first: 2, second: 4, second: 5"`

Also: `max_returns` is the maximum number of retrieved results total. So if my example had a `max_returns = 3`, then the output would have been:
`"first: 1, second: 3, fourth: 6"`

**Question:** Is there a better, or more efficient way to grab data from multiple arrays in a round robin fashion?

Comment: Shoun'd that be `second: 3` in the first instance? `{label: "second", data: ["3", "4", "5"]}`

Comment: You are correct, thanks for finding that! I have revised my example to match.

Comment: `round-robin` is not a valid method name and there seem to be a `TypeError` when appending `element[:data][j]` to the `result` string

Comment: @Stefan You are correct, I hastily created the method name and example data and failed to check it thoroughly enough. I have corrected my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
arr = [{ label: "first",  data: [1, 3] },
       { label: "second", data: [3, 4, 5] },
       { label: "third",  data: [] },
       { label: "fourth", data: [6] }]

results = []
arr.each do |h|
  h[:data].each_with_index do |d, i|
    results[i] ||= []
    results[i] << "#{h[:label]}: #{d}"
  end
end

results.flatten.join(', ')
#=> "first: 1, second: 3, fourth: 6, first: 3, second: 4, second: 5"
```

Comment: Best answer so far, imo. Readers: Stefan could have written this as a one-liner, but chose not to do so, presumable to make it easier to follow. The compressed form would be: `arr.each_with_object([]) { |h,results| h[:data].each_with_index { |d, i| (results[i] ||= []) << "#{h[:label]}: #{d}" } }.flatten.join(', ')`. Stefan, I presume you have a good excuse for being absent over the holidays.

Answer (score 3):

```
▶ input = [{label: "first", data: [1, 2]},
           {label: "second", data: [3, 4, 5]},
           {label: "third", data: []},
           {label: "fourth", data: [6]}]

▶ max = input.max_by { |e| e[:data].size }[:data].size

▶ input.map do |h|
    [[h[:label]] * max].flatten.zip h[:data] # make it N×M (for transpose)
  end.transpose.map do |e|
    e.reject { |_, v| v.nil? }               # remove nils
  end.flatten(1).map { |e| e.join ': ' }.join ', '

#⇒  "first: 1, second: 3, fourth: 6, first: 2, second: 4, second: 5"
```

Without two last joins the result would be an array of arrays:

```
#⇒ [["first", 1], ["second", 3], ["fourth", 6], 
#   ["first", 2], ["second", 4], ["second", 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [{ label: "first",  data: [1, 2] },
       { label: "second", data: [3, 4, 5] },
       { label: "third",  data: [] },
       { label: "fourth", data: [6] }]

labels, data = arr.map { |h| [h[:label], h[:data].dup] }.transpose
  #=> [["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [], [6]]] 
data.map(&:size).max.times.with_object([]) do |_,arr|
  labels.each_index do |i|
    d = data[i].shift
    arr << "#{labels[i]}: #{d}" if d
  end
end.join(', ')
  #=> "first: 1, second: 3, fourth: 6, first: 2, second: 4, second: 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is round robin, but here is the solution which gives an output you need:

Version based on initial array elements removal:

```
arr = [{label: "first", data: [1, 2]}, {label: "second", data: [3, 4, 5]}, {label: "third", data: []}, {label: "fourth", data: [6]}]

loop do
  arr.each do |hash|                               # go through each hash
    num = hash[:data].delete_at(0)                 # remove first element in data array
    puts "#{hash[:label]}: #{num}" unless num.nil? # output it if it's not nil(means array was empty)
  end
  break if arr.map { |i| i[:data] }.flatten == []  # stop if all arrays are empty
end
```

Version which doesn't change initial array:

```
arr = [{label: "first", data: [1, 2]}, {label: "second", data: [3, 4, 5]}, {label: "third", data: []}, {label: "fourth", data: [6]}]

max_data_size = arr.map { |i| i[:data] }.map(&:size).max
loop.with_index do |_, i|
  arr.each do |hash|
    num = hash[:data][i]
    puts "#{hash[:label]}: #{num}" unless num.nil?
  end
  break if i >= max_data_size - 1
end
```

Comment: I used your second version in the benchmarks. When I changed the data to fit better to the problem, your solution ran a little slower than it had with my first run of benchmarks, so I changed the answer to @stefan's. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 1):

The benchmarks were all run against the same data. I ran each answer against four different scenarios:
`*_5` were run against the original data: 852, 0, 0, 0
`*_500` were run against the same data but with a maximum of 500 returns.
`*_2_5` were run against data in 4 arrays the sizes were: 656, 137, 0, 59, total 852 records.
`*_2_500` were run against arr2 with a maximum return of 500.

```
                       user     system      total        real
OP_5:              0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000120)
Mudasobwa_5:       0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000108)
Cary_5:            0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.011316)
Rustam_5:          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000087)
Wand_5:            0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.003761)
Stefan_5:          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004007)
OP_500:            0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.017235)
Mudasobwa_500:     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006164)
Cary_500:          0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.011403)
Rustam_500:        0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.011884)
Wand_500:          0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.003743)
Stefan_500:        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002711)
OP_2_5:            0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000052)
Mudasobwa_2_5:     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000140)
Cary_2_5:          0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008196)
Rustam_2_5:        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000088)
Wand_2_5:          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003338)
Stefan_2_5:        0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.002597)
OP_2_500:          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002211)
Mudasobwa_2_500:   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006373)
Cary_2_500:        0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008455)
Rustam_2_500:      0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.019453)
Wand_2_500:        0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.004846)
Stefan_2_500:      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003421)
OP_avg:            0.002500   0.002500   0.005000 (  0.004904)
Mudasobwa_avg:     0.002500   0.000000   0.002500 (  0.003196)
Cary_avg:          0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.009843)
Rustam_avg:        0.007500   0.000000   0.007500 (  0.007878)
Wand_avg:          0.007500   0.000000   0.007500 (  0.003922)
Stefan_avg:        0.002500   0.000000   0.002500 (  0.003184)
```

Contrary to my previous benchmark, the average indicates that Stefan's answer is actually the fastest by beating Mudasobwa's answer by 0.000012 seconds!

**Note:** I had to edit some of the answers to imitate what my original solution was trying to do, so there are some extra things in the benchmark code which were added on purpose.
Also, some solutions did not use the `max_returns` limit (or didn't stop at the limit) which caused them to take longer than others (I blame myself for a less-than-stellar explanation when I originally asked the question). I did not take into account the `max_returns` limit in choosing the answer because the only solutions that obeyed it were mine and Wand's (see gist for details).

The code and sample data to execute these benchmarks can be found here: https://gist.github.com/scytherswings/65644610e20037bb948c

Thank you everyone for your answers!

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark (even though I came in last). When you report a benchmark it's best to include the benchmark code (including the data, or a method that generates the data). That way, readers can run the benchmark after making modifications to their methods. Which of @Rustam's two methods did you run? To make it comparable to the other methods you should use the second one, which does not mutate the array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have updated the benchmarks with much better data and Stefan's answer. Thanks for the encouragement, I've learned a lot from this question and I had fun doing it too. Cheers!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Oh, and to answer your eariler question, I did use the second version of Rustam's answer ;)